# Javascript access TDs from closest TR. Javascript PHP Session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, code-snippets

I am using this snippet: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/payment-form-with-total-preview

And my problem is on the X click, when removing an element, I would like to access the value of the TDs (Concept, Description, Amount, Status and Date), in order to, after having those values, removing the element from my PHP session array, which is an array of all the payments, so I just would do an unset based on the values I get.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$(document).on('click', '.input-remove-row', function(){ 
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    var tds = tr.children('td');

    var txt = $(tds[0]).text()
    var txt1 = $(tds[1]).text()
    var txt2 = $(tds[2]).text()

    document.write (txt1)

    tr.fadeOut(200, function(){

        tr.remove();
        calc_total()
    });
});
```

I have trying printing the value of txt, txt1 and txt2 but I always get the amount, I don't reach the other tds, and they are all supposed to be tds with class input based on the other function.

Another question would be how to handle the session here, but that's not the highest priority issue.

Any idea¿? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I copied your snippet, add what you write here, but I get the right result: [Demo](http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/V0dkd), maybe you should check again?

Comment: Really? Can you access all the values or the TR? I don't know whats going on but I can only access the amount, no matter what position I try

Comment: Ah, so the snippet can be access directly, I have to make a jsfiddle or something...

Comment: I am not registered I didn't see it.

Yes what I did worked, apparently I wasn't reloading the website so the changes were not updated, apparently I am stupid xDDDD

So the question now would be how to easily remove from an a PHP session array based on that, thank you

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwhnec6r/), yep, happy to see you find it out when I create a jsfiddle demo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : 
If you want to use php to store session value, then you should use `$.ajax`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.input-remove-row', function(){ 
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    var tds = tr.children('td');

    var txt = $(tds[0]).text()
    var txt1 = $(tds[1]).text()
    var txt2 = $(tds[2]).text()

    var data = {
      concept: txt,
      description: txt1,
      amount: txt2
    };

    $.ajax("YOUR_PHP_POST_URL", {
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        //Check if store success
        if (POST_SUCCESS) {
          // remove tr and calc total here
          tr.fadeOut(200, function(){
             tr.remove();
            calc_total();
          });
        } else {
          //notify store failed...
        }
      },
    });
});
```

When you want the sessioned data, you can use:

```
$.ajax("YOUR_PHP_GET_URL", {
  success: function(response) {
    // convert reposnse to object
    // then do something like append this data to table, and calc_total
  },
});
```

Or if you use `PHP` to create the page, you can directly put those session data on table while rendering.

For more about ajax, go to [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and you can also find more details, examples on internet.

Comment: I mean modifying the PHP session using the javascript value

Comment: Got it, changed my answer.

Comment: Well, It seems a very good answer, but where do you just remove from the $_SESSION['payments'] and in the same javascript file, there is another button to add, where I would like to append in the $_SESSION['payments'], I just have 2 files, one js and 1 php, like the snippet (changed the html to php) so how to perform it.... I don't know if I can contact u personally or something somehow

Comment: I don't know why "PHP POST URL" and "PHP GET URL" if there is only one PHP, so if there are one request that appends and one removes from the session array, how to carry that out¿? Thank u very much really

Comment: My email is fuyushimoya@gmail.com , you can contact me by that, but its 6am now, so the reply would be 4 hours late imo.